# sort array without conditional

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, counting-sort

I need a program that sorts an array of integers without using conditional statements. Numbers are in the range from 0 to 100 and don't repeat.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 34, 12, 24, 65, 63, 22 };
    int arraySize = (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr));
    unsigned char buf[101] = { 0 };

    for (int k = 0; k < arraySize; k++) {
        buf[arr[k]]++;
    }

    unsigned char i = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k <= 100; k++) {
        arr[i] = k;
        i += buf[k];
    }

    for (int a : arr) {
        cout << a << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This program works but I get the error after closing of the command prompt:

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'arr' was corrupted.

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: which compiler are you using ?

Comment: "works" may be a bit strong.

Comment: You're writing out of bounds somewhere. Use a debugger and step through the code, line by line, while keeping an eye on the variables and their values.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2015

Comment: The second `for` loop is writing outside the `arr` array. I think you meant `arr[k] = i;`.

Comment: @Barmar That would *really* write out of bounds of `arr`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You're right, I was think it was `buf[k] = i`.

Comment: why you dont use `std::sort` ?

Comment: @Barmar You were on the right way though, and gave me a hint of the problem. :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Glad I could help! This does look like a clever algorithm, modulo the bug.

Comment: I did not see any problem : https://ideone.com/LjPhB0

Comment: @VenkataNaiduM It's undefined behavior, it won't necessarily cause an error message. He's using an implementation that adds extra checks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your code writes past the end of the array. It happens after you have encountered the last element in the counted sequence, but before the array `buf` has been exhausted, i.e.

```
for (int k = 0; k <= 100; k++) {
    arr[i] = k;
    i += buf[k];
}
```

When you add the highest element, which is 65, to the result, `i` reaches 6, so assigning `a[i]` becomes illegal. See what's going on by adding an extra element to your array, setting it to -1, and watching what happens to it (it gets set to 100; [demo 1](http://ideone.com/vbeogo)).

You can fix it by adding an early exit condition to stop as soon as you filled the array back, i.e.

```
for (int k = 0; i < arraySize && k <= 100; k++) {
    arr[i] = k;
    i += buf[k];
}
```

Now the -1 past the end of "active" part of our array remains -1 ([demo](http://ideone.com/yOVRSD)).

Answer (score 2):

The logic of the second loop is wrong. You have six numbers in `arr`, no doubles, which means that a total of six elements in `buf` will be set to `1`.

That means that after a while, the value of `i` will be `6`, which you then use as an index into `arr`, but index `6` is the *seventh* element in an array, leading you to write out of bounds.